# Visual Studio C++/MFC: how to prevent menu at top of CDialog from wrapping (or get the screen size of the menu)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, menu, mfc

In Visual Studio C++ (2017) I have a resizable dialog with a menu at the top. If the user makes the dialog smaller, eventually the top menu wraps around. I need to either:

1. prevent the menu wrapping around (presumably so some menu items are missing)
2. or calculate the screen size of the menu so that I can calculate the positions of things in the rest of the dialog

Any ideas how I can do one or both of these?

Comment: Why don't you specify a limit to how small it can become? There is a procedure for that. This way it won't go smaller than you designed it to.

Comment: I have limited the minimum dialog size, but the minimum size I would like still has the menu bar wrapping around. Furthermore I don't know when the menu wraps around so don't know when to make the necessary adjustments to positioning things in the rest of the dialog.

Comment: You receive a `WM_SIZE` message when the user resizes your dialog. In the `OnSize()` handler call `GetClientRect()` to get the size of the client area which excludes the menu bar. So you actually don't need to know the size of the menu bar.